# Compare input string entered by user with url

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Problem:** I want to do is basically compare a string take it as `https://www(dot)facebook(dot)com` with user entered input.

So when user enters - `https://www(dot)facebook(dot)com/blabla` it should advance when he clicks the next button but is should show invalid url if he enters like `https://www(dot)google(dot)com`

In short input url should contain `https://www(dot)facebook(dot)com` and it doesn't matter what is after it. Everything after is should be treated fair and user should be able to move forward.

Also I need to compare it with mobile version ie. `https://m(dot)facebook(dot)com`

If the user input STARTS from any of these inputs ie, `https://www.facebook.com` or `https://m.facebook.com` he should be able to move forward when he clicks next or some similar button.

P.S Used (dot) because I cannot post links

Comment: What about using strpos() ? http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: The problem with strpos is it only has to be in the string, not necessarily the URL

Comment: I don't want to use the url of the website on which the user is, I mean like if my string is set to be https://www.facebook.com and user enters https://www.facebook.com/blablabla.. will strpos work?

Comment: Yes it will work, but it will also work with https://blahblah.facebook.com/blablabla... as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about preg_match()?

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/blabla';
$isFacebook = preg_match("/https:\/\/.*\.facebook.com/i",$url,$match);
//$isFacebook is 1 when the url is correct.
//$match[0] contains "https://www.facebook.com"
```

Comment: the result will be the same. (sorry for late answer ;) )

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
$url = "https://www.facebook.com/blah-blah.html";
$parts = parse_url($url);

if (strpos($parts["host"],".facebook.com")) {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

This will make sure that you are checking the correct part of the URL.

Comment: hello bro can you please Pm me or something like that, I want to chat more regarding this. The thing which I am doing is kinda tough for me and I'm not able to code. Help